# Add or modify columns(fields/tags) of influxdb with collectd

Tags: influxdb, collectd, influxdb-python

I tried to implement my own python plugin of collectd which can store data into  influxdb.

I followed this site's tutorial: https://blog.dbrgn.ch/2017/3/10/write-a-collectd-python-plugin/

and also other tutorials.
Following is the sample code from the site above.

```
PATH = '/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp'
def config_func(config): 
    path_set = False 

    for node in config.children: 
        key = node.key.lower() 
        val = node.values[0] 

        if key == 'path': 
            global PATH 
            PATH = val 
            path_set = True 
        else: collectd.info('cpu_temp plugin: Unknown config key "%s"' % key) 
        if path_set: 
            collectd.info('cpu_temp plugin: Using overridden path %s' % PATH) 
        else: collectd.info('cpu_temp plugin: Using default path %s' % PATH)

def read_func(): 
    # Read raw value 
    with open(PATH, 'rb') as f: 
    temp = f.read().strip() 

    # Convert to degrees celsius 
    deg = float(int(temp)) / 1000 

    # Dispatch value to collectd 
    val = collectd.Values(type='temperature') 
    val.plugin = 'cpu_temp' 
    val.dispatch(values=[deg])

collectd.register_config(config_func) 
collectd.register_read(read_func)
```

I tried it and it stored the data in the influxdb, but how can I add or modify the columns name (or it should be field and tag in terms of influxdb)?

After successfully running the sample code, I saw the column names are time, host, type, type_instance and value in the influxdb.
However, I was quite confused about where are these column name being set?

In /etc/collectd.conf or in the script, there is no such setting about these column names.
What if I want to add a new column or modify the column name such as 'type' to another name like 'resource'?

Is it possible to add more columns or modify these columns? Where can I find how theses name are named?

Thanks~

Comment: Need to show your script to be able to help. In general, tags/fields are set on write in influxdb. So it'll be in your script, which you'll need to show.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I update my questions. Thanks for your help~